# Eclipse not running: "An error has occured"

Tags: eclipse-cdt

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, when I run Eclipse CDT, after selecting the workspace, I get an error message

> An error has occured. See the Log file. /home/workspace/.metadata/.log.

I've tried a newer version of Eclipse with the same results.

[image: Log file]

Answer (score 0):

My IT person was able to get eclipse past this error by changing the permissions on eclipse from root to my username.
I don't know if this was the proper way to fix this issue but it worked.